# Check if image column is Null VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Good Day everyone. I need help with my code below.

Dim stream As New MemoryStream()

```
        connect()
        Dim command As New SqlCommand("SELECT image FROM tblHouseholdMembers WHERE id= '" & lvmem.FocusedItem.Text & "'", cn)
        Dim image As Byte() = DirectCast(command.ExecuteScalar(), Byte()) --> 'Error message of null image
        stream.Write(image, 0, image.Length)
        cn.Close()
        Dim bitmap As New Bitmap(stream)
        pbProfilePic.Image = bitmap
```

I want to put a messagebox to identify if it's null before the error cast.

Comment: Sorry, What I want is the software tell the user that he/she select member with a null image. I hope you understand me. :)

Comment: If you want to make your question clearer, then edit the question (using the **edit** link under the question); that is not what comments are for.

Comment: Im sorry @ZevSpitz. Next time I'll do it that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the DirectCast method, use the TryCast and then check if the casting result is nothing:

```
Dim image As Byte() = TryCast(command.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())
if image isnot nothing then
    stream.Write(image, 0, image.Length)
    cn.Close()
    Dim bitmap As New Bitmap(stream)
    pbProfilePic.Image = bitmap
else
    'Error message here
end if
```

Comment: @YevrahAradnop If this answer resolves your question, then accept it (using the checkmark next to the answer).

Comment: @AugustoQ I want to know too how can I insert Image using Update query. because I have some information with Null Image I need to put image when I click update Button. thnx once again

Comment: @YevrahAradnop Using an update statement  is pretty similar to the insert statement. This [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/437937/Save-and-Retrieve-Image-from-a-SQL-Server-Database) might help you updating.

Answer (score 0):

The way to directly test if a field coming back from a database is null is:

```
if ValueFromDb is System.DbNull.Value then
  ' whatever you want to do in that case
```

Something that really confused me when I was first learning VB is that a null value from a DB read is NOT equal to Nothing. It is not Nothing, it is System.DbNull.Value.

Most of my projects these days,  I write a little function I call "denull" that says something like:

```
public shared function denull(value as object, defalt as object)
  if value is system.dbnull.value then
    return defalt
  else
    return value
end function
```

Then I wrap every value I read from the db in this function. This saves a lot of code.

```
for each row in mydataset.tables(0).rows
  foo=denull(row("foo"),"")
  bar=denull(row("bar"),0)
  plugh=denull(row("plugh"),nothing)
  ... etc ...
```

Comment: But the code of @AugustoQ is worked perfectly. But maybe I'll give it a try for System.DbNull.Value

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that AugustoQ's solution would not work, I was just trying to offer the more general case. His solution will work because dbnull.value is not of type byte() and thus the cast will fail. Note that he does not compare the return value from ExecuteScalar to nothing, but the return value from the TryCast.